# Angular1.x and angular2 together

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Is there any problem to use **angular2** in a website that uses **angular 1.x** **theme** (HTML theme develeoped using angular 1.x). 
Any challenges need to be faced while developing?

Comment: What do you mean by "angular theme"?

Comment: I mean the html themes in the market developed using angular1.x

Comment: HTML themes? If you're asking if you can port the HTML/CSS then yes, but don't expect any of the angular specific attributes/bindings to work.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I guess he is saying that the first version of his app was made with Angular 1.x.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Angular (Angular2) components inside an AngularJs (Angular1)  application by using `downgradeComponent` function of [upgrade module](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#how-the-upgrade-module-works). Check this [documentation link.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#using-angular-components-from-angularjs-code)

```
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail.component';
/* . . . */
import { downgradeComponent } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
angular.module('heroApp', [])
  .directive(
    'heroDetail',
    downgradeComponent({component: HeroDetailComponent}) as angular.IDirectiveFactory
  );
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please select it if it's useful. ;) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work